# Auto-wiring not working in overridden `get()` method of Supplier Interface in spring-boot

Tags: java, multithreading, spring-boot

I have a class named WorkerThread which overrides get() method 
 of implemented Supplier Interface. Inside WorkerThread class auto wiring of MockService is happening but when while calling methods of those services it throws NullPointerException.

I have created @PostConstruct init() method in MockService with logs which are getting printed on startup. Also If I remove the method calls of MockService the code works fine.

SomeServiceImpl.java (calling class for WorkerThread)

```
//initializing engine pool for processing which will be responsible for providing engine Objects
            Supplier<OcrData> callable = new WorkerThread( enginesPool, imageFile, scanId, pageCount, saveOcrContent,
                maxLangConsideration, pageThreshold, preprocess, outputFolder, saveInMongo );
            response = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync( callable, executorService );
```

WorkerThread.java

```
@Component
public class WorkerThread implements Supplier<OcrData>
{
    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger( WorkerThread.class );

    private boolean SAVE_IN_MONGO;
    private String outputFolder;
    private Boolean preprocess;
    private Integer pageThreshold;
    private Integer maxLangConsideration;
    private Boolean saveOcrContent;
    private EnginesPool enginesPool;
    private File imageFile;
    private String scanId;
    private String threadId;
    private Integer pageCount;

    private DocumentProcessor documentProcessor;
    private MockService mockService;
    private DummyService dummyService;

    @Autowired
    public void setMockAbbyyService( MockService mockService )
    {
        this.mockService = mockService;
    }


    @Autowired
    public void setDocumentProcessor( DocumentProcessor documentProcessor )
    {
        this.documentProcessor = documentProcessor;
    }


    public WorkerThread()
    {
    }


    public WorkerThread( EnginesPool pool, File source, String imageKey, Integer pageCount, Boolean saveOcrContent,
        Integer maxLang, Integer threshold, Boolean preprocess, String outputFolder, boolean saveInMongo )
    {
        enginesPool = pool;
        scanId = imageKey;
        this.saveOcrContent = saveOcrContent;
        maxLangConsideration = maxLang;
        pageThreshold = threshold;
        this.preprocess = preprocess;
        this.outputFolder = outputFolder;
        this.pageCount = pageCount;
        this.SAVE_IN_MONGO = saveInMongo;


        File reducedResolutionImage = null;
        try {
            boolean performPreprocess = this.preprocess;
            if ( performPreprocess ) {


                if ( pageCount > pageThreshold ) {
                    reducedResolutionImage = documentProcessor.getPreprocessedImage( imageFile );
                }
            }
        } catch ( Exception ex ) {
            LOG.error( "Error while getting preprocessed image for scanId: {}", ex, scanId );
        }
        if ( null != reducedResolutionImage ) {
            imageFile = reducedResolutionImage;

        } else {
            imageFile = source;
        }
    }


    @Override
    public OcrData get()
    {
        Response response = null;
        OcrData ocrData = new OcrData();
        this.threadId = String.valueOf( Thread.currentThread().getId() );
        try {
            LOG.info( "Thread {} started ", this.threadId );

            if ( imageFile != null ) {
                LOG.info( "Thread {} processing scanId: {}", this.threadId, scanId );
                try {
                    // SAVE_IN_MONGO false got for ocr
                    LOG.info( "Value of save in mongo {}", SAVE_IN_MONGO );
                    // SAVE_IN_MONGO flag to check mock abbyy
                    if ( SAVE_IN_MONGO ) {
                        // SAVE_IN_MONGO true get reponse from mongo if found then return
                        LOG.info( "fetching data from mongo" );
//HERE it fails complaining for null
                        if(mockService != null) {
                            response = mockService.getResponse( imageFile );
                        }else {
                            LOG.warn( "Could not autowire mock service." );
                            response = null;
                        }
                        LOG.info( "data fetched from mongo with response: {}", response!= null?"data exist":"no data found" );
                        // response not found
                        if ( response == null ) {
                            // submit for ocr
                            LOG.info("submiting request for ocr");
                            response = processImageFile( imageFile );
                            LOG.info("response for ocr : {}", response!=null?"ocr done": "ocr failed");
                            if ( response != null ) {
                                // saving result in mongo
//HERE also it fails
                                mockService.saveTo( response, imageFile );
                            }
                        }
                    } else {
                        // otherwise go for ocr.
                        response = processImageFile( imageFile );
                    }
                    //build ocrDate response object
                    ocrData.setResponse( response );
                    ocrData.setStatus( ScanRequestStatus.OCRED.getStatus() );
                } catch ( Exception ex ) {
                    LOG.error( "Thread {}:  Error caused {} for processing scanId: {}", this.threadId, ex, scanId );
                    ocrData.setException( ex );
                    ocrData.setStatus( ScanRequestStatus.FAILED.getStatus() );
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            LOG.info( "Thread {} finished ", this.threadId );
        } catch ( Exception ex ) {
            LOG.error( "Error occurred while processing requests in parallel with exception {}", ex );
        }

        return ocrData;
    }


    private Response processImageFile( File imageFile ) throws Exception
    {
        //code to process 
    }
}
```

MockService.java

```
public interface MockService
{
    String getImageKey( File file );

    Response getResponse( File file );

    void saveTo( Response responseFrom, File file );
}
```

MockServiceImpl.java

```
@Service
public class MockServiceImpl implements MockService
{
    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger( MockServiceImpl.class );
    private MockRepository mockAbbyyRepository;


    @Autowired
    public void setMockRepository( MockRepository mockRepository )
    {
        this.mockRepository = mockRepository;
    }

   @PostConstruct
    public void postConstruct(){
        // this log is getting printed
        LOG.info( "After constructing MockService object" );
    }

    @Override
    public String getImageKey( File file )
    {
        LOG.debug( "Getting image key for file {}", file.getName() );
        FileInputStream fin = null;
        byte fileContent[] = new byte[(int) file.length()];

        try {
            fin = new FileInputStream( file );
            fin.read( fileContent );
        } catch ( FileNotFoundException e ) {
            LOG.error( "Exception found while getting image key", e );
        } catch ( IOException e ) {
            LOG.error( "Exception found while getting image key", e );
        } catch ( Exception e ) {
            LOG.error( "Exception found while getting image key", e );
        }

        String s = new String( fileContent );

        String imageKey = sha256Encoding( s );

        return imageKey;
    }


    @Override
    public AbbyyResponse getAbbyyResponse( File file )
    {
        // code to get response  
    }


    @Override
    public void saveTo( AbbyyResponse responseFrom, File file )
    {

        // code to save the response
    }


    private String sha256Encoding( String phrase )
    {
        return Hashing.sha256().hashString( phrase, StandardCharsets.UTF_8 ).toString();
    }

}
```

please share your inputs for this issue.
Thanks in advance

Comment: I am seeing that you have created an object of worker thread class. Spring annotations only works on spring managed beans.

Answer (score 2):

`Supplier<OcrData> callable = new WorkerThread()` can not be autowired.

To get a spring managed bean,

```
Supplier<OcrData> callable = applicationContext.getBean(WorkerThread.class);
```

or

```
Supplier<OcrData> callable = new WorkerThread();
AutowireCapableBeanFactory beanFactory = applicationContext.getBean(AutowireCapableBeanFactory.class);
beanFactory.autowiredBean(callable);
```